# Nested concept types in templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

Consider the following template, intended on declaring some `State::Machine`:

```
enum Strategy {
   Breadth,
   Depth,
   Heuristic,
};

template<class Map, Strategy Strategy = Depth>
struct Machine;
```

If we would like to enforce some constraints on the `Map` type, so that implementations satisfy necessary concepts, we have:

```
template <Range::Type Source, Comparable Constraint, class Result, Transition<Source, Constraint, Result> Transition, Range::Of<Transition> Transitions, Map<Constraint, Transitions> Map, Strategy Strategy = Strategy::Depth>
class Machine {

};
```

Where `Source` is some `container` like `std::vector`, `Constraint` is some comparable `struct == struct -> bool`, `Transition` is some `lambda(Source) -> Product` and `Transitions` is some `container` of `Transition`.

Declaring this type is now exhausting:

```
auto transition = [](std::string source) {
    return State::Product<std::string, State, State> {
            .source = source,
            .state = State::Start,
            .product = State::Start,
    };
};
static_assert(Transition<decltype(transition), std::string, State, State>);

std::map<State, std::set<decltype(transition)>> map = {
        {State::Start, {transition}}
};

State::Machine<std::string, State, State, decltype(transition), std::set<decltype(transition)>, decltype(map)> machine;
```

Is there a way to have all the concepts be required with only one type parameter

```
State::Machine<decltype(map)> machine;
```

Similar to how it was before any concepts were required?

Comment: I don't understand this question. Why is `Machine` going from taking one type parameter to taking... six type parameters? What does it actually need?

Comment: it is also unclear what you mean with "Similar to how it was before any concepts were required?". Introduction of concepts didnt deprecate already existing techniques. Concepts are not "required". If you knew how to do it before concepts it should still work

Comment: @Barry It's likely I'm not asking a sensible question and the design is poor. I intend for a `Machine` implementation is a consumer of `Source` with some initial `State` to generate a sequence of `Product` types which have some `Result`, next `State`, and partially consumed `Source`.  In order to produce that, each `Machine` has a `Map` of `State` to some `Transition`, where `Transition` is a lambda that takes a `Source` and returns such a `Product`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes, the single type parameter Map is enough to define an implementation, but does not provide very concise or helpful compilation errors when the implementation is incorrect. I am trying to enforce all the necessary constraints on the Map type that the implementation for `Machine` will use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most types expose their "subtypes".
[`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) has `key_type` and `mapped_type` for example.

(You can create traits to extract template parameter if needed BTW, if type doesn't provide such `typedef`).

Then you might use constraint on those sub-types, something like:

```
template <typename Map, Strategy Strategy = Strategy::Depth>
requires(Comparable<typename Map::key_type>
     && IsATransition<typename Map::mapped_type>)
class Machine
{
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to extract template parameter types?

Comment: Something like [that](https://godbolt.org/z/Mjb73Eozz).

Comment: What is the right way to constrain the sub-types of a given type when the sub-types are variadic and therefore, there are no helper-types like `key_type` and `mapped_type`? I can imagine some sort of hacky-solution where the given type has a helper-type such as `using tuple_type = std::tuple<Ts...>;`, and then unpacking it within a requires-clause with the use of a templated lambda. But this is far from ideal since it requires having to construct a `tuple_type` and it makes type-constrain error messages really poor and obscure.

Comment: There are still extern helper such as [ `std::tuple_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_element) (to extract n th type of a tuple) if type doesn't provide appropriate alias.